# Move map to user's position

Tags: android, google-maps

I thought this would be really simple but how can you move the map to the user's current location?

map.getMyLocation() seems to be returning a null value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the current location of the user you should get it from a LocationListener after you have the location use this to set it on the map

```
   // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```